# Creating a custom List view & set Target audience for that List view web part using Client object model

Tags: client-object-model, list-view, provider-hosted-app, audience-targeting

I am working in a provider hosted app in O365 SP Online and I want to create a SP list view programatically.

How do I do that?

**Edit:1**

But the tricky part I have is apart from fields, I want to set up target audience as well

**Edit:2**
If I use this custom List view in a List view web part then how will I be able to set target audience for the same. [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c3c78200-1649-4545-849e-b76689d38dfc/set-target-audience-for-list-view-web-part-using-powershell-csom?forum=sharepointgeneral) is the similar thread which explains how to do it using powershell. But I need some reference in C#

Comment: Have you tried something? There are plenty of ressources answering that question - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-view-in-sharepoint-2013-using-csom for example.

Comment: I have updated my question, please refer. Anyway why a negative score on my question, I m still not able to figure it out! If this an invalid one or something